# SUM of two rows returned by SQL subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, subquery

I have created the following SQL query

```
SELECT ae.[intEntitlementID] 
      ,SUM(decIncrease) - SUM([decDecrease]) as quantity
                ,(SELECT SUM([decCredit]) - SUM([decDebit]) as value
                FROM [tblMonetaryValueEvent]
                where [intEntitlementID] = ae.intEntitlementID
                and intSchemeYear <= @intSchemeYear
                group by intEntitlementID) AS VALUE
    ,(SUM(decIncrease) - SUM([decDecrease])) *
                (SELECT SUM([decCredit]) - SUM([decDebit]) as value
                FROM [tblMonetaryValueEvent]
                where [intEntitlementID] = ae.intEntitlementID
                and intSchemeYear <= @intSchemeYear
                group by intEntitlementID) AS TOTAL



  FROM [tblAllocationEvent] ae

  where ae.intBusinessID = @intBusinessID
  and ae.intSchemeYear <= @intSchemeYear
  group by ae.intEntitlementID

  HAVING SUM(decIncrease) - SUM([decDecrease]) > 0
```

Which returns the following

[image]

I now need to find the sum of the two rows on the TOTAL column.

I want the following data to be output. 73046.908322 + 1150.946103

Does anybody have any tips on how to SUM the two results returned by the sub query?

Thanks

Comment: What does *"I now need to add the two rows in the TOTAL column but I am having trouble doing this."* mean? We don't have access to your data, and you don't show us the desired result.

Comment: you have lot of scope to improve in your script. Can you please post some sample data with expected output? this will help.

Comment: Apologies desired result has now been added to main body and below.

My desired result is the sum of 73046.908322 and 1150.946103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @mkRabbani said, you could improve your query...
I think next one might be
- more readable
- perform better (but I cannot test, because no data)

so, untested!:

```
WITH sums AS (
  SELECT 
    ae.[intEntitlementID]
    ,SUM(decIncrease)-SUM(decDecrease) AS quantity 
    ,SUM(decCredit)-SUM(decDebit) As value
  FROM [tblAllocationEvent] ae
  INNER JOIN [tblMonetaryValueEvent] ON [intEntitlementID] = ae.intEntitlementID
                                  and intSchemeYear <= ae.intSchemeYear
  where ae.intBusinessID = @intBusinessID
  and ae.intSchemeYear <= @intSchemeYear
  group by ae.intEntitlementID
)
SELECT
  intEntitlementID
  ,quantity
  ,value
  ,quantity * value as Total
FROM sums
```

Answer (score 1):

use [ROLLUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT i, count(*) as c, sum(i) as s
FROM TEST
WHERE i<5
GROUP BY ROLLUP(i)
```

gives:

```
i   c   s
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   1   4
NULL    4   10
```